# Creating TFS new Team project using REST API

Tags: tfs-2015

I am trying to create Team projects using REST APIs. I have followed the [Link:](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects)

I am able to create the project just like we can using the web portal.

I am trying to create a project which has SharePoint and Reporting integration, which is not in case of web portal and REST API as far as I know.

Need suggestion on ways of achieving the same with automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't support to create a team project using API with Reporting service and Sharepoint site. The only way is using Visual Studio/Team Explorer to create.

Maybe you could run the [tfpt addprojectreports command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/upload-reports#upload-reports-to-your-team-project-tfs-2015-and-earlier-versions) in your code to configure reports for your new team project of TFS 2015. And use [tfpt addprojectportal command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/sharepoint-dashboards/configure-or-add-a-project-portal#a-nameaddspa-add-sharepoint-site-integration-and-upload-portal-contents-from-a-process-template) to configure Sharepoint in your code. To use these  command, you need to install TFS Power Tool.

Comment: well doing it manually is not an option, may be there is something on .Net apis if you can suggest. Since Team explorer can do it, so can we make any use of that fact. I am not sure how Team explorer does it, or will it have any api exposed.

Comment: @Angshuman I have just confirmed again and changed my reply. You could also use command to configure sharepoint site for your team project. Unfortunately, althrough Team Explore could do that but it doesn't provide any API method for use to use. So as a workaround, you write the command in your code.

Comment: thanks a lot I will try them out. Marking the answer as accepted.